# How can I make a copy of a disk in a Datastore with the vSphere REST API?

Tags: rest, vsphere

Using the vSphere REST API, I would like to make a copy of a vmdk into a new file so that I can create a new disk with this copied vmdk as it's backing. How could this be achieved with the vSphere REST API that was introduced in 6.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that functionality is not yet available in the vSphere Automation REST APIs.

Currently you can only list the VM's disks, get information about a specific disk for a VM, reconfigure which VMDK a VM is using, add a new VMDK, and delete a VMDK.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/doublecloudinc/vim-rest-api

Also, vBrownBag tech talk: https://youtu.be/EpMlP27gEEM

Disclaimer: I am the creator of the REST APIs that supports FULL features of vSphere APIs, and scales across many vCenter/ESXi servers.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Something I noticed while messing around with the API is that the [VM Clone method](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/vmactionclone/post/) would do a deep copy of any attached vmdk files.

So you could use this to do a deep copy of a hard drive. Which worked for my case.

### Solution 2

If this is a bit messy for your situation, you can enabled SSH on the ESXi box and then use that to copy a file.

### Solution 3

If you don't like the security implications of opening the SSH port then you can use an undocumentation internal API with the ESXi host to perform a copy. Here is a script that does just this:
https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware/blob/main/plugins/modules/vsphere_copy.py